# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown with Tags Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, stoppropagation

I have a question with Twitter Bootstrap, I'm using the Dropdown plugin and I'm trying to create a tag selector, I created an example in this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/gatnc/

I've tried this:

```
event.stopPropagation;
return false;
```

Does anyone have a better solution that does not close the dropdown when selecting a tag?

**Note:** Click on "New Tag".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'li', function(event){...});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gatnc/4/)

Comment: Hey @dgilland, can you help me with something else? Click exactly on the input, it will not be selected.

EDIT: Fixed! http://jsfiddle.net/gatnc/5/

Comment: Awesome - no idea how google suggested this page first from the query 'intercept dropdown anchor' but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with "live" it's bound to the document. This means the close event won't get intercepted by stopPropagation. If you're using jQuery 1.7.1, you can swap out "live" for "on", like so:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event) {
```

That'll bind the event to the element, and then things like stopPropagation will work.

Comment: I think what Mike meant to say is that with `live()`, the event is bound to the `document` so `event.stopPropagation()` doesn't get fired until it's too late.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Good catch, have an upvote while I steal your correction

Comment: @MikeRobinson, thanks! But don't work when I click in "New Tag" and then click on the tag was added, the dropdown disappear. http://jsfiddle.net/gatnc/2/